# Is Nothing the subclass of R when I use sealed class in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I often see the following Code A about sealed class in Kotlin.

1: By the structure of the `sealed class Result`,it seems that `Nothing` just like the subclass of `R`, right?

2: I think Code A should be Code B, is it right?

3: And more, it seems that I never see the code just like Code C, is it wrong?

**Code A**

```
sealed class Result<out R> {
    data class Success<out T>(val data: T) : Result<T>()
    data class Error(val exception: Exception) : Result<Nothing>()
}
```

**Code B**

```
sealed class Result<out R> {
    data class Success<out R>(val data: R) : Result<R>()
    data class Error(val exception: Exception) : Result<Nothing>()
}
```

**Code C**

```
sealed class Result<out R> {
    data class Success<out T>(val data: T) : Result<T>()
    data class Fail<out K>(val data: K) : Result<K>()
}
```

**Added Content**

To Joffrey: Thanks!

In Code 1 , `Noting` is just look like the subclass of `R`

I think Code 2 is easy to understand more then Code 1, right?

**Code 1**

```
sealed class Result<out R> {
    data class Success<out T>(val data: T) : Result<T>()
    data class Error(val exception: Exception) : Result<Nothing>()
}


val cityDetails: Result<ExploreModel>
        get() {
            val destination = destinationsRepository.getDestination(cityName)
            return if (destination != null) {
                Result.Success(destination)
            } else {
                Result.Error(IllegalArgumentException("City doesn't exist"))
            }
      }

if (cityDetails is Result.Success<ExploreModel>) {
      ...
 } else {
      onErrorLoading()
}
```

**Code 2**

```
 sealed class Result<out R> {
        data class Success<out T>(val data: T) : Result<T>()
        data class Error(val exception: Exception) : Result<Nothing>()
    }

 val destination = destinationsRepository.getDestination(cityName)
 val cityDetails= if (destination != null)  Result.Success(destination) else Result.Error(IllegalArgumentException("City doesn't exist"))

 if (cityDetails is Result.Success<ExploreModel>) {
     ...
 } else {
     onErrorLoading()
}
```

**Add content again:**

By the declaration of the class `Result`, `out R` and `out T` can be different type, and  `out R` and `out T` can be any type.

Why is Code 3 correct, and Code 4 wrong?

Does it mean that `T` must be the subclass of `R` in `sealed class Result`?

BTW， Code 5 can be compiled.

**Code 3**

```
sealed class Result<out R> {
    data class Success<out T>(val data: T) : Result<T>()
    data class Error(val exception: Exception) : Result<Nothing>()

 }

  val cityDetails: Result<ExploreModel>
    get() {
        val destination = destinationsRepository.getDestination(cityName)
        return if (destination != null) {
            Result.Success<ExploreModel>(destination)
        } else {
            Result.Error(IllegalArgumentException("City doesn't exist"))
        }
    }

if (cityDetails is Result.Success<ExploreModel>) {
  ...
} else {
  onErrorLoading()
}
```

**Code 4**

```
sealed class Result<out R> {
    data class Success<out T>(val data: T) : Result<T>()
    data class Error(val exception: Exception) : Result<Nothing>()

 }

  val cityDetails: Result<String>      //It's String type
    get() {
        val destination = destinationsRepository.getDestination(cityName)
        return if (destination != null) {
            Result.Success<ExploreModel>(destination)
        } else {
            Result.Error(IllegalArgumentException("City doesn't exist"))
        }
    }

 if (cityDetails is Result.Success<ExploreModel>) {
  ...
 } else {
   onErrorLoading()
 }
```

**Code 5**

```
   sealed class Result<out R> {
      data class Success<out T>(val data: T) : Result<T>()
      data class Fail<out K>(val data: K) : Result<K>()
   }

   val aa:  Result1<Any>
          get(){
             return if (true) Result1.Success("Hello") else Result1.Fail(3)
          }
```

**Add content thirdly:**

To Joffrey: Thank you very much!

Your answer is great, I can understand completely, thanks again

Anyway, I think the Code Ok is better than the Code 1, it's clear without any ambiguous, right?

**Code OK**

```
sealed class Result<out R> {
    data class Success<out T>(val data: T) : Result<T>()
    data class Error(val exception: Exception) : Result<Nothing>()
}


val cityDetails: Result<Any>
        get() {
            val destination = destinationsRepository.getDestination(cityName)
            return if (destination != null) {
                Result.Success(destination)
            } else {
                Result.Error(IllegalArgumentException("City doesn't exist"))
            }
      }

if (cityDetails is Result.Success<ExploreModel>) {
      ...
 } else {
      onErrorLoading()
}
```

Comment: I thought you were asking generally about how to write sealed classes, but given your example, I should point out that the `Result` class already exists in Kotlin stdlib

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1: By the structure of the sealed class Result,it seems that Nothing just like the subclass of R, right?

The `Nothing` type is a subtype of every type, because there are no values of that type.

But to say that it's a subtype of `R` is sort of incorrect, because `R` is not really defined here. You are declaring a class `Error`, and you "input" `Nothing` as a value for the type parameter `R` of the class `Result`, just like you would pass arguments to a method.

`Nothing` is useful when you have a generic type parameter (like `R` here) from a parent class that you don't use anywhere in the class. It's not meant to be used even in the parent, so `Nothing` shows it more clearly.

> 2: I think Code A should be Code B, is it right?

Code A and B are completely identical to the compiler. Those type parameters are just variable names. I guess using a different name avoids "shadowing" and makes it easier to follow.

> 3: And more, it seems that I never see the code just like Code C, is it wrong?

Code C is not wrong, it just doesn't serve the same purpose. In the first case the failure case encapsulates a `Throwable`, and in code C it encapsulate a value of a given type. It's totally ok to declare multiple subclasses with type parameters.

---

Answer to the edited question:

In your updated example, Code 1 and Code 2 don't do the same thing. The first one recomputes the value every time it's accessed, while Code 2 sets it once and never changes it again

---

Answer to the second edit:

> By the declaration of the class `Result`, `out R` and `out T` can be different type, and `out R` and `out T` can be any type.

> Does it mean that `T` must be the subclass of `R` in sealed class Result?

I think you are confusing generic variance and simple subtyping of generic types. They are tightly related, but let me try to clarify.

`T` and `R` are type parameters. This means that when you instantiate a `Result.Success` object, you choose a type for `T`. Or when you instantiate a `Result` object, you choose a type for `R` (it's technically not possible to instantiate `Result` directly because it's an abstract class, but still).

I think what you're missing is that the `T` of the `Result.Success<T>` class ***is*** the `R` of the `Success` class. This is defined by the declaration:

```kotlin
data class Success<out T>(val data: T) : Result<T>()
```

This means that instances of `Result.Success<T>` object ***are also*** instances of `Result<T>` (the same `T`!). Because `Result.Success<T>` is a subtype of `Result<T>` (the same `T`!).

For instance if you write `Result.Success<ExploreModel>(destination)` (like in your Code 3), you choose `T=ExploreModel`, and by definition of this class the instance ***is also a*** `Result<ExploreModel>`.

Similarly, when you write `Result.Error(IllegalArgumentException("City doesn't exist"))`, you create an instance of `Result.Error` which is also an instance of `Result<Nothing>` (by definition of the `Result.Error` class).

Now let's talk about variance. For a given generic type, like `Result<R>`, you can define a type hierarchy between different "versions" of this type using different types as `R`.

With the `out` keyword, you declare `Result<out R>` as "covariant in R", which means that if `Dog` is a subtype of `Animal`, `Result<Dog>` is a subtype `Result<Animal>`.

Now this should clarify why this is valid:

```kotlin
val cityDetails: Result<ExploreModel> = Result.Success<ExploreModel>(destination)
```

But this is not:

```kotlin
val cityDetails: Result<String> = Result.Success<ExploreModel>(destination)
```

It's not really about `T` being a subtype of `R`, it's about `R` being a subtype of another `R` if you want to assign a `Result<R>` instance to a variable of a `Result<R>` type with a different value of `R`:

```kotlin
val cityDetailsModel: Result<ExploreModel> = Result.Success<ExploreModel>(destination)

val cityDetailsStr: Result<String> = cityDetailsModel // invalid
val cityDetailsAny: Result<Any> = cityDetailsModel // valid
```

So yes, because `Result` is covariant in `R` (`out R`), you can only assign instances of `Result<R>` to variables of type `Result<R or a supertype of R>`.

I hope it's clearer now why saying `T` needs to be a subtype of `R` is not really correct and is a shortcut that may bring confusion, that's why I refrain from writing it this way.

Comment: Thanks! Would you please to see my added content in the question?

Comment: In your updated example, Code 1 and Code 2 don't do the same thing. The first one recomputes the value every time it's accessed, while Code 2 sets it once and never changes it again

Comment: Thanks! Would you please to see my added content again in the question?

Comment: @HelloCW I updated my answer. I hope this clarifies things

Comment: Thanks! Would you please to see my added content thirdly in the question?